# Allowed countries in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Does anyone know of a way in which the allowed countries can be overwritten in the phtml files of the adminhtml?

We have a specific set of allowed countries on the front end, which we set using the option in the config. If someone phones up to place and order, we would like the advisers to be able to pick any country when creating an order in the backend/admin panel.

Previously we had a separate store set up, solely for phone orders - but this was creating issues with indexing being too big.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can select the countries you want to have available in the admin panel in the **default** configuration and override them on **website** level with the countries you want to have available in the frontend.

When creating an order from the backend, you always have the countries from the default configuration, regardless which website or store view you choose.

Comment: Ah great - did not realise this.

Comment: Sorry - this hasn't actually worked. When I press 'add order' in the back end of Magento and select a customer and store they still just have the options for that specific store.

I have all countries set on default level.